# Testing text of an element using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'd like to validate the text of an element (p element, for instance) with the help of Cypress.
I have used this code:

```
cy.get('#word').should('have.value', 'Color')
```

and I received this:
expected <p#word> to have value Color, but the value was ''
Evidently, it validates the CSS but not the html element value. How can I validate the element content here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asserting the inner Text, instead of `have.value` you have to use `have.text`.

```js
cy.get('#word').should('have.text', 'Color')
```

Or, If you want to assert a partial string, you can use `include.text`

```js
cy.get('#word').should('include.text', 'Color')
```